# proFTPd -- Operation not permitted on line 36 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'

Tags: proftpd

`sudo chown proftpd /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
 sudo chmod o-r /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
 sudo service proftpd start`

At this stage proFTPd is running but I am unable to log in,

`sudo chmod o+r /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd`

And now I can log in to FTP
However if I change the permission on the ftpd.passwd to `sudo chmod o+r /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd` **before** I start the proFTPd , the proFTPd won't start and will give me the error:

`mod_auth_file/1.0: unable to use world-readable AuthUserFile '/etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd': Operation not permitted
 Fatal: AuthUserFile: unable to use /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd: Operation not permitted on line 36 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'`

What my suspicion is that proFTPd is not a member of a specific group, if I execute:

`groups proftpd`

`proftpd : nogroup` is the reply.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the permissions of the file when the service won't start?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 proftpd root  Aug 10 13:18 ftpd.passwd ===> proftpd won't start

 -rw-r----- 1 proftpd root  Aug 10 13:18 ftpd.passwd ==> ProFTP starts, but unable to login

after ProFTPd started I change the permission again back to -rw-r--r--  and it works/I can log in to FTP

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change permissions of password file.

```
sudo chmod o-rwx /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd

sudo service proftpd start
```

(alternative way: `sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd start`)